# Parsing text file in Perl and store information in JSON

Tags: json, perl, parsing

So, I have this file that contains different paths for different files and what type of file change it was with the number of changes in the lines. Something like this

```
abc123:
  Files Changed:                             lines: new    deleted  unchanged
    some/path/to/file.c                              15      0           4234
    some/other/file.h                                 1      0            223
    some/other/path/to/file2                          3      1              3
  Files Created:                             lines: new    deleted  unchanged
    some/path/to/file.c                               3      1              3           
  Files Changed:                             lines: new    deleted  unchanged
    some/other/path/to/file                           2      2            234
```

I need to find an easy way to parse this. I really don't care the lines changes( new, deleted, unchanged). What I want is to have a JSON. Something like this:

```
{
    "abc123":{
        "Files Changed:": [ 
            "some/path/to/file.c",
            "some/other/file.h",
            "some/other/path/to/file",
            "some/other/path/to/file2"
         ],
        "Files Created:":[
            "some/path/to/file.c"
         ]
     }
}
```

The harder part is to try to parse the text file I want something that can work with anything the file gives you. What I know for sure might work is anything that has a '/' then is a file string but I don't know how to tell wether it was a 'File Changed' or 'File Created'. Also, The file might have something like 'Files Deleted' 'Files Link' with their corresponding file paths. Any help in how to achieve this would be appreciate it.

Comment: If the whitespace on the beginning of the lines is consistent, this is pretty easy to achieve. You just need to read line by line and remember what you saw last on which level. Is this git output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the whitespace on the beginning of the lines is consistent, this is very easy to achieve. You need to read line by line and remember what you saw on which level.

In the following code, I'm assuming two spaces of indentation per level. Since this looks like some sort of version control summary, I'm calling

- the 0th level of indentation *abc123* `$commit`,
- and the 1st level the `$operation` that has been done to the files listed below.
- The 2nd level contains file names.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON 'to_json';

my $commit; # abc123
my $operation; # Files Changed, Files Created
my $data; # this is the target

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ /^(\S+):/) {
        # line contains a commit
        $commit = $1;
        next;
    }
    if ($line =~ /^\s\s([^:]+):/) {
        # line contains an operation
        $operation = $1;
        next;
    }
    if ($line =~ /^\s\s\s\s(\S+)/) {
        # this is a filename
        push @{ $data->{$commit}->{$operation} }, $1;
    }
}

print to_json $data;

__DATA__
abc123:
  Files Changed:                             lines: new    deleted  unchanged
    some/path/to/file.c                              15      0           4234
    some/other/file.h                                 1      0            223
    some/other/path/to/file2                          3      1              3
  Files Created:                             lines: new    deleted  unchanged
    some/path/to/file.c                               3      1              3
  Files Changed:                             lines: new    deleted  unchanged
    some/other/path/to/file                           2      2            234
```

This produces the following output.

```
{"abc123":{"Files Changed":["some/path/to/file.c","some/other/file.h","some/other/path/to/file2","some/other/path/to/file"],"Files Created":["some/path/to/file.c"]}}
```

Comment: You are a life savior!. Didn't think about the spaces. It worked! thanks!